# How do I build a 5-bit maximal-length Galois LFSR in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, lfsr

[image: Circuit Diagram of LFSR]

I'm having a problem with getting the desired output.

Here is my code:

```
module top_module(
    input clk,
    input reset,    // Active-high synchronous reset to 5'h1
    output reg [4:0] q
); 
    wire din3;

    assign din3 = q[3] ^ q[0];
    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        if (reset)
            q <= 5'd1;
        else
            q <= {q[0],din3,q[2],q[1],q[0]};
    end
endmodule
```

This is the timing diagram of my output vs the correct output.

[image: Timing Diagram]

Also I keep getting this error:

> Warning (13024): Output pins are stuck at VCC or GND

The Testbench code is not available to me because it's done behind the scenes on the [HDLBits website](https://hdlbits.01xz.net/wiki/Lfsr5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wiring errors.

```
module top_module(
    input clk,
    input reset,    // Active-high synchronous reset to 5'h1
    output reg [4:0] q
); 

    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        if (reset)
            q <= 5'd1;
        else
            q <= {q[0], q[4], (q[0] ^ q[3]), q[2], q[1]};
    end
endmodule
```

---

Note: you can see the HDLBits solution if you make an attempt on the site.  For example, I typed in the legal (but wrong) solution: `assign q=0;`.